# Is it possible to automate Notepad++, specifically the search and replace across files?

Tags: script, notepad++, automation

Is it possible to automate Notepad++, specifically the search and replace across files?

I want to be able to automate the search and replacement of placeholder values across a number of file types, e.g. .config and .pubxml, and rather than write PowerShell script, I'd prefer to use the ready built (and tested) functionality in Notepad++

Comment: @PJMahoney Yeah, but I find UI automation a bit on the brittle side ... I was hoping for an accessible API for driving N++ through PowerShell or the like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's so many ways for achieving this. I'll stick to the ones that uses Notepad++ for now

1. ***Notepad++ > Search > Find in Files*** and go from there adjust the mask or make backups, and read your option this WILL replace all files in sub folders by default

   ### OR
2. for more advanced search and replace ***Notepad++ > Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager*** now search for and Install "Python Script" [read here for more](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/). This require some basic coding skills or you'll need to read and test for a while.

---

if you're looking for a command-line tool you can use [fnr.exe - Find And Replace Tool](https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/), It's a simple and effective Open source tool It's portable, free, lightweight and more Stable than basic codes that we may create.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to item 2. I don't think item 1 is a valid answer, as it's purely manual, which I already do. I wanted to automate the process.

Comment: Please note that option number 1  will find and replace text of ALL FILES in a folder and sub folders and will save the modified files automatically.

Comment: Updated Answer.